# where.not with where in rails/activerecord excluding all records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model (pairings) that has a length and date attribute (among others). I am trying to query all pairings that do NOT touch a specific date or date range while matching other properties of the pairing. The code for all other queries working fine, but my where.not is excluding all records. This is because (I think) of the way I am building the relation/query.

I need something that excludes selected date range AND matches the length. This needs to be stacked on other scoped queries.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Controller code:

```
rel = rel.other scoped queries
@all_trip_len.each do |len|
 rel = rel.date_selector(@date_sel_1, @date_start_1, @date_end_1, len)
end
rel = rel.more scoped queries
```

Model Scope:

```
def self.date_selector(sel, start_d, end_d, length)
 # Need to get all possible start dates that could touch avoid days for each length of trip
 rel = self
 start = Date.parse(start_d) - (length.to_i - 1)
 rel = rel.where.not(date: start.to_s..Date.parse(end_d).to_s).where(length: length)            
 return rel
end
```

I am getting a query that is:

```
SELECT "pairings".* 
FROM "pairings" 
WHERE "pairings"."bid_month_id" = $1 
  AND NOT ("pairings"."date" BETWEEN $2 AND $3) 
  AND "pairings"."length" = $4 
  AND NOT ("pairings"."date" BETWEEN $5 AND $6) 
  AND "pairings"."length" = $7 [["bid_month_id", 8], ["date", "2020-04-08"], ["date", "2020-04-08"], ["length", 1], ["date", "2020-04-07"], ["date", "2020-04-08"], ["length", 2]
```

And I need something more like:

```
SELECT "pairings".* 
FROM "pairings" 
WHERE "pairings"."bid_month_id" = $1 
  AND NOT (("pairings"."date" BETWEEN $2 AND $3) 
           AND "pairings"."length" = $4) 
  AND NOT (("pairings"."date" BETWEEN $5 AND $6) 
           AND "pairings"."length" = $7) [["bid_month_id", 8], ["date", "2020-04-08"], ["date", "2020-04-08"], ["length", 1], ["date", "2020-04-07"], ["date", "2020-04-08"], ["length", 2]
```

**Edit:**

With the help of MurifoX I got a little farther. The query is built almost correctly but I need OR in between the pairing.date grouping.

What I have now:

```
SELECT "pairings".* 
FROM "pairings" 
WHERE "pairings"."bid_month_id" = $3 
  AND (((date <= '2020-04-06' AND date >= '2020-04-07') AND length = 1)) 
  AND (((date <= '2020-04-05' AND date >= '2020-04-07') AND length = 2))
```

What I need:

```
SELECT "pairings".* 
FROM "pairings" 
WHERE "pairings"."bid_month_id" = $3 
  AND (((date <= '2020-04-06' AND date >= '2020-04-07') AND length = 1) 
       OR ((date <= '2020-04-05' AND date >= '2020-04-07') AND length = 2))
```

I have tried using the rails 5 or (rel.or(Pairing.date_selector(xxx)) but that does not work because it turns all the where AND into OR and I just need the OR between the pairing/date groupings. Also need the parens around the date groupings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to build this as a string to get it to do exactly what I want. the or relation in rails 5 created a statement that OR'd ALL of my previous scope clauses with the new one (all AND -> OR) and I needed all my previous scoped queries to stand and just the new dates to be OR'd.

```
def exclude_dates(rel, date_start_1, date_end_1, all_trip_len)
    dates_query = String.new
    count = 0 
    all_trip_len.each do |len|
     start_d = Date.parse(date_start_1) - (len.to_i - 1)
     end_d = Date.parse(date_end_1)
     count += 1
     dates_query += " OR " if count > 1
     dates_query += "((date < '#{start_d.to_s}' OR date > '#{end_d.to_s}') AND length = '#{len}')"
    end
rel = rel.where(dates_query)
end
```

This created the query I needed. Wish there was a more 'rails' way to do it...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "pairings" WHERE "pairings"."bid_month_id" = $1 AND (((date < '2020-04-02' OR date > '2020-04-02') AND length = '1') OR ((date < '2020-04-01' OR date > '2020-04-02') AND length = '2') OR ((date < '2020-03-31' OR date > '2020-04-02') AND length = '3') OR ((date < '2020-03-30' OR date > '2020-04-02') AND length = '4')) AND (((date < '2020-04-14' OR date > '2020-04-17') AND length = '1') OR ((date < '2020-04-13' OR date > '2020-04-17') AND length = '2') OR ((date < '2020-04-12' OR date > '2020-04-17') AND length = '3') OR ((date < '2020-04-11' OR date > '2020-04-17') AND length = '4'))  [["bid_month_id", 8]]
```

Thanks to @MurifoX for getting me going in the right direction with the dates stuff!

Answer (score 2):

The construction of semi-complex queries with ActiveRecord methods can be tricky sometimes, so in this particular cases i always tell people to do it by hand:

```
rel = self
start = Date.parse(start_d) - (length.to_i - 1)
rel = rel.where("((date <= ? AND date >= ?) AND length = ?)", start.to_s, Date.parse(end_d).to_s, length)
return rel
```

Comment: This got me very close. I think I need to have an OR statement between the different date/length queries though (it's an AND right now). Any idea how to accomplish that? `SELECT "pairings".* FROM "pairings" WHERE "pairings"."bid_month_id" = $3 AND (((date <= '2020-04-06' AND date >= '2020-04-07') AND length = 1)) AND (((date <= '2020-04-05' AND date >= '2020-04-07') AND length = 2))`

Comment: @ATP_coder Rails have OR too, check this out: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/30/rails-5-adds-or-support-in-active-record.html

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. I went through that before asking my question here. It creates an OR for ALL relations/scopes that you do. I still needed some AND. Answered my Q below. Thanks for getting me started in the right direction!